# Rails asynchronous ajax request rendered multiple times

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I am using rails with script response to ajax calls.  I click a button, the ajax is called, and a set of items is rendered in response and added to the page.

If I click the button rapidly (say 10 times), 10 response sets will be rendered.  However, in my logs I will only see 6 posts (or 7 depending how fast I click), the same number of database entries, and same number of responses rendered.  In Chrome, I also only 6 posts on the network tools tab.

If I set the jquery call to be async:false (which I understand is bad?), I seem to have no problems.

I am using Unicorn in Development if that makes a difference.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here (and how I can fix it)?  How are post responses getting rendered when there are no responses?  Is this a UJS race condition?

Answer (score 0):

As I was reading, I suspected this would be the case; your `async: false` experiment seemed to confirm it (whether it's right is another story):

---

**Server**

I'd surmise your `Ajax` requests are being throttled by the server

I don't know exactly how this would be the case, but the idea that you're sending 10 requests; and only having 6 / 7 calls initialized, means not all your requests are getting through

---

**Ajax**

The reason why `async: false` is bad is because it freezes your browser until the synchronous request has been handled

This means that if you're sending a single request each time, your server will be able to handle it & return the data accordingly. Obviously, it will be bad for UX if you do this, but that's another story

---

**Recommendation**

Personally, I think the problem may be that your setup of Unicorn [cannot handle concurrent connections](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110323155416AAQgIIX), or something similar. Although [Unicorn *can* handle concurrency](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/2/27/unicorn_rails), maybe your setup in development only gives it 1 worker or something?

Basically, your issue would make sense if your server only responded to 1 request at a time. That would mean your "missed" ajax responses would only be lost when unicorn is too busy to handle the request

Comment: I have 2 workers set up with unicorn, could set up more.  I guess my main question is why is a response is rendered even in the case when the server appears to have been sent and received nothing?  ie I get 10 'item sets' added to my list, even though according to my logs and Chrome only 7 posts are made?  If I add log entries to the js.erb file I get 7 log entries but the javascript is called 10 times, how is that possible? Thanks